# Cross Domain Request and JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, cross-domain

Im trying to make a cross domain request to a web service via jquery using $.getJSON() and it works fine!  However, when I try to make the same request in Internet Explorer 7 or 8 the request is never sent.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSONP is here for this purpose. Check the JSONP section in [getJSON jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Answer (score 0):

IE explicitly blocks cross domain requests. Better to use a cross domain proxy on your server for better results!

Some documentation: http://ajaxpatterns.org/Cross-Domain_Proxy

Comment: Problem with that is my code is distributed to others websites that i dont have any control over.