# Making AJAX calls from customer site to my own server over HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross Domain Request and JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006588/cross-domain-request-and-jquery)

I'm currently making the transition from Windows application programming (most recently C# / WPF) to web programming. I apologize in advance for what may be a remedial question.

Here's the scoop:

I've developed a little UI component that retrieves some industry-specific information from my servers via an AJAX call and displays it in an elegant way. I'm not sure if web programmers use the term "component" like Windows developers do, but I'm just referring to a single set of HTML code, a .css file, and a .js file. I want to package these three small files as a bundle and sell them to a number of clients [financial institutions] so that they can embed my component in their own sites.

The component has been tested. It works on my domain. But I'm running into a problem when trying to allow outside users to use the information on their own domain. The issue is:

The AJAX call needs to query https://ajax.MyDomain.com but my customer's site lives at https://www.SomeOtherDomain.com. I understand that there are plenty of good reasons that browsers disallow this sort of cross-site call. But how do web developers approach this sort of situation?

The only thing I can come up with is telling the customer to create a DNS CNAME named ajax.SomeOtherDomain.com that points to ajax.MyDomain.com. The script could then point to the that hostname, and since that hostname lives within the customer's domain, that would solve the cross-site issue (I think, I haven't tried yet). But even if I beat that hurdle, I'm still faced with the SSL certificate issue. My web server would need to be bound to a certificate bearing the name "ajax.SomeOtherDomain.com" in order to handle the inbound AJAX calls. This would require the the customer's permission. Asking a financial institution to buy a new cert (containing their own domain name!) and just give it to me for use on my server is too much to ask. Even if they agreed, I'd be uncomfortable with it.

I can't be the first person to face this. What approach should I take?

Comment: You're correct, read up on jsonp.
Jquery handles this well I've found.

Comment: Covered quite extensively: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross+domain+ajax http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cross+domain+json